# Excel Formula: IF(OR(AND( with Array

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm using an Excel sheet to validate data. It's a relatively simple validation on the amount paid vs. lowest available cost. Based on certain logic a code is attached to each record to explain why the lowest available cost was not used, etc.

In my worksheet column I represents the amount paid, J the lowest available cost, and K the highest known cost for the item/service. Column Q contains the code (e.g. CC, LL, BC, and so forth).

This is the formula I am currently using:

```
=IF(OR(AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="LL"),AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="EX"),AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="ER"),AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="EV"),AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="CD"),AND(J2<I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2={"BB","BC","CC","CD","DD","FF","QQ","RR","XA","XC"})),"Good","Error")
```

The last portion does not work consistently:

`AND(J2<I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2={"BB","BC","CC","CD","DD","FF","QQ","RR","XA","XC"})`

For example, I have a line in which J2 is less than I2 and Q2 = RR and results in "Error" when it should really be "Good".

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what does `H2<>"ZZ"` means?

Comment: That is used to filter out transactions that do not need to be validated. ZZ in H2 means it is an exempt vendor.

Comment: Did you tried to validate your `AND` section only?

Comment: If I understand your correctly, yes. For example, =IF(OR(AND(J2=I2,H2<>"ZZ",Q2="LL") - that works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the array part in an `OR()`:

```
AND(J2<I2,H2<>"ZZ",OR(Q2={"BB","BC","CC","CD","DD","FF","QQ","RR","XA","XC"}))
```